# Reading shared variables [affected in sub report] in page header of the main report

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

my problem is that in the page header section of the main report I display the value of a shared (Shared NumberVar x) variable

I am trying to modify the contents of this variable in 2 different sections of the report (Section 1 => Shared NumberVar x: = 1, Section 2 => Shared NumberVar x: = 2) then I assign the variable x = 3 in sub report (Shared NumberVar x: = 3 in the sub report)

the problem is that the result of the x variable in the page header section have not changed to 3 and remains 2 after displaying the sub report

Crystal Reports don't allows reading shared variables in the header section as the page header comes before sub report

is there another solution so that I can read a shared variable assigned in a sub report in the header of the main report ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible because of the way variables and subreports are evaluated. In the main report you can re-assign a variable pretty much in every section of the report as long as the report hierarchy is correct. You do that with the correct use of `WhilePrintingRecords;` and `WhileReadingRecords;` With subreports, even if you declare the variable with `WhileReadingRecords;` in the subreport, the `WhilePrintingRecords;` to display your variable gets evaluated at the same time as the subreport. So the subreport has to be placed higher in the hierarchy than the formula that displays your variable. [Here](http://book.soundonair.ru/sams/ch04lev1sec6.html) is a great diagram on the different passes a report makes when it runs.

Comment: well, i understand. but is there another way to solve this problem, and to get the evaluated variable in sub report. thanks

Comment: I'm not quite clear on why you need to assign a different value to the same variable in each section of your report. Maybe elaborate on that a little in your original question and then we can see if there is another way of doing what you are after.

Comment: I found a solution I deducted the number of pages displayed by the sub report and according to the number of detected page I change the variable in the page header section of the main report, thanks